# Update SQL Server from WPF datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to make a page in an app which will use a datagrid to allow users to view and edit data from a SQL Server database. I would like changes to be saved back to the database immediately after they are made by the user.

I have been trying the CellEditEnding event with SqlCommandBuilder to update the database as edits are made; but after every change it shows 0 updates and nothing is saved.

I can see that the changes in the datagrid are reflected in the datatable, and there is an `UpdateCommand` generated, but no change is made to the database.

Is there something here that I have missed?

Alternatively is there a way to manually create an update command based on the data in the edited row?

I am new to C# and WPF so any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have tried using a manually generated `UpdateCommand` and it still does nothing, so I believe the problem occurs around  `adapter.Update(dt);`. For some reason the data is not saving to the database from the datatable.

Code:

```
public partial class pgMain : Page
{
    private SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    private DataTable dt;

    public pgMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connPlanDB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AdvProdApp].[dbo].[Orders] WHERE Position > 0 AND Hidden = 0 ORDER BY Linje, Position", cnn);

            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            ICollectionView indata = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dt.DefaultView);
            indata.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Linje"));

            Tbl_Plan.DataContext = dt;

            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Cannot connect to database");
        }
    }

    private void Tbl_Plan_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connPlanDB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();

            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            int u = adapter.Update(dt);
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            MessageBox.Show(u.ToString());

            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Cannot connect to database");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="Tbl_Plan" Margin="100,30,50,100" AlternatingRowBackground="Beige" AlternationCount="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="900" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CellEditEnding="Tbl_Plan_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
                                            <TextBlock Text=" Linje " FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Plandate" Binding="{Binding Plandate}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nr" Binding="{Binding Nr}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ordernr" Binding="{Binding Ordernr}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ursprungsnr" Binding="{Binding Ursprungsnr}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kundnr" Binding="{Binding Kundnr}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kundnamn" Binding="{Binding Kundnamn}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duedate" Binding="{Binding Duedate}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Antal" Binding="{Binding Antal}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Optisk_Ref" Binding="{Binding Optisk_Ref}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gen Info" Binding="{Binding sign_Geninfo, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Optisk Start" Binding="{Binding sign_Optiskstart, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Optisk Slut" Binding="{Binding sign_Optiskslut, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ingen Optisk Ref" Binding="{Binding sign_Ingenoptisk, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Efterblandad" Binding="{Binding Efterblandad, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ändringar" Binding="{Binding Ändringar, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kgh" Binding="{Binding Kgh, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding Notes, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: How do you define the columns? Or are they auto-generated?

Comment: They are all ´DataGridTextColumn´ with two way binding on the columns I want to allow the user to edit.

Comment: Try to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the column bindings to `PropertyChanged`: `Binding="{Binding Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`. This should cause the source property to get set immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that the DataTable is being updated with the change from the DataGrid, but then that change is not being passed on to the database.